# C++ fstream doesn't read whole file

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

Edit:

I found my error. It was with the text file itself. I managed to make two different sized text files; and referenced the wrong file when comparing sizes.

To all to commented and replied, I did consider all the feedback. thanks!

<s>working on a lab for a university class. I've been having a tough time figuring out how to read the entire contents of a .txt file that contains the complete text for 'Alice in Wonderland'.</s>

Some context:

This is just the starting point for building an openCL program that will do a MapReduce for a string search (ie. count the number of times "Alice" shows up in the text). The program is being compiled and run on a Ubuntu virtual machine; compiled later for an FPGA.

Ubuntu tells me the file size is 148,545 bytes.
My code is saying 53073 bytes. It also doesn't read out the whole file when I try to print it out.

Functionally, the code currently works on a chunk of the file (Alice in Wonderland text). But it doesn't seem to read/search through the entire text. I've been searching high and low for an answer to my plight, but I've been unsuccessful.

So!
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "CL/opencl.h"
#include "AOCL_Utils.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    string line;
    long wordMatch, wordLength;
    wchar_t* inputLine;
    ifstream inputText;
    inputText.open("alice.txt", ifstream::binary | ifstream::in); // Open the text
    inputText.seekg(0, ios::end);
    int length = inputText.tellg(); // Gives back the wrong byte size
    cout << length << "\n";
    inputText.close();

    char * textBuffer = new char [length];
    wordMatch = 0;

    inputText.open("alice.txt"); // Could've just seeked to the start

    inputText.read(textBuffer, inputText.gcount()); 

    //cout << inputText.gcount() << " bytes in file \n"; // Trying to get correct bytesize

    while(getline(inputText,line)) // Read out the text, but stops before it's finished
    {
        cout << line << "\n";
    }

    inputLine = (wchar_t*) "Alice"; // What we're counting occurrences of

    // My little counting routine. Works fine.
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (textBuffer[i] == inputLine[0])
        {
            wordLength = 0;
            if (textBuffer[i] == inputLine[0]) {
                while (textBuffer[i+wordLength] == inputLine[wordLength]) { 
                    //cout << textBuffer[i+wordLength] << " and " << inputLine[wordLength] << "\n"; 
                    wordLength++;
                }
                if (inputLine[wordLength] == 0) {
                        wordMatch++;                    
                } 
            }

        }

    }
    inputText.close();
    cout << length << " bytes \n";
    cout << wordMatch << "\n";


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a memory leak in your code. You should deallocate ``textBuffer`` once you don't need it

Comment: Why `(wchar_t*) "Alice"`? `textBuffer[i] == inputLine[0]` will very rarely be true (and you're checking it twice).

Comment: why do you have `ifstream::binary | ifstream::in` use either or `|` should be used for `in` and `out` modes not `binary` and `in` since they are both writing modes.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the problems in your posted code is in the line:

```
inputText.read(textBuffer, inputText.gcount());
```

I suspect, the internal counter that is returned by `gcount()` is set to zero once you close the file and reopen it.

When I changed that line to:

```
int n = inputText.gcount();
cout << "n: " << n << "\n";
inputText.read(textBuffer, n);
```

I got

```
n: 0
```

as output.

I would change that line to:

```
inputText.read(textBuffer, length);
```

Comment: So, I've tried this. I tried it before I asked the question online, and just to be sure, I did it again. Still returning the same incorrect file length and won't load the whole file.

Comment: @BaleineBoy, that is strange. Perhaps you have a corrupted hard disk.